# Use result of other querys in final query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use a result of two other tables in my "final" result

Query 1 (Result: DaysUntilNow = 3) :

```
SELECT SUM(WorkingDay) AS DaysUntilNow 
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Salesboard Working Days] 
WHERE CompanyCode = 'Selek Danmark' 
AND WorkingDay = 1 
AND [Date] >= '2020-07-01' 
AND [Date] <= '2020-07-03' 
AND SalesPersonCode IS NULL
```

Query 2 (Result: DaysInPeriod = 22)

```
SELECT SUM(WorkingDay) AS DaysInPeriod 
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Salesboard Working Days] 
WHERE CompanyCode = 'Selek Danmark' 
AND WorkingDay = 1 
AND [Date] >= '2020-07-01' 
AND [Date] <= '2020-07-30' 
AND SalesPersonCode IS NULL
```

From Query 1 i get DaysUntlNow, and from Query 2 i get DaysInPeriod

I want to use result of query 1 and 2 in my "final" query as like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(ABS(SUM(e.[Amount])),0) AS Amount
        , '3' AS DaysUntilNow
        , '22' AS DaysInPeriod
        , ISNULL(ABS(SUM(e.[Amount])) / 22,0) As BudgetPerDay
        , ISNULL(ABS(SUM(e.[Amount])) / 22,0) *3 As BudgetUntilNow
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Selek Danmark$G_L Budget Entry] AS e
WHERE e.[Budget Name] = '2020C' 
AND e.[G_L Account No_] LIKE '3%' 
AND e.[Date] = '2020-07-01'
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Hi, what database do you use ?

Comment: Oh sorry. using MS SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use `WITH` statement

```sql
WITH query1 AS (
  SELECT 1 as FOO
),
query2 as (
  SELECT 2 as BAR
)

SELECT FOO, BAR FROM query1,query2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] >= '2020-07-01' AND [Date] <= '2020-07-03' THEN WorkingDay ELSE 0 END) as DaysUntilNow
       SUM(WorkingDay) AS DaysInPeriod 
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Salesboard Working Days] 
WHERE CompanyCode = 'Selek Danmark' AND
      WorkingDay = 1 AND
      [Date] >= '2020-07-01' AND
      [Date] <= '2020-07-30' AND
      SalesPersonCode IS NULL;
```

You can then include this in your final query:

```
WITH d as (
      SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] >= '2020-07-01' AND [Date] <= '2020-07-03' THEN WorkingDay ELSE 0 END) as DaysUntilNow
             SUM(WorkingDay) AS DaysInPeriod 
      FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Salesboard Working Days] 
      WHERE CompanyCode = 'Selek Danmark' AND
            WorkingDay = 1 AND
            [Date] >= '2020-07-01' AND
            [Date] <= '2020-07-30' AND
            SalesPersonCode IS NULL
      )
SELECT COALESCE(ABS(SUM(e.Amount)), 0) AS Amount,
       dDaysUntilNow, d.DaysInPeriod,
       COALESCE(ABS(SUM(e.Amount)) / 22, 0) As BudgetPerDay,
       COALESCE(ABS(SUM(e.Amount)) / 22,0) * 3 As BudgetUntilNow,
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Selek Danmark$G_L Budget Entry] e CROSS JOIN
     d
WHERE e.[Budget Name] = '2020C' AND
      e.[G_L Account No_] LIKE '3%' AND
      e.[Date] = '2020-07-01'
```